# How to use Actions class in Selenium WebDriver/facebook WebDriver using phpunit?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I am using facebook php webdriver and I want to use Actions class to mouse hover on an element, trying different ways to do so, but not working. please help me where I am going wrong!
Here is the code-

```
{
        $this->webDriver->get($this->url);
        $id = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id("email"));
        $id->sendKeys("email");

        $pass = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id("password"));
        $pass->sendKeys("passwd");

$login = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("//input[@value='Login']"));
        $login->click();

        $this->assertContains('dashboard/site',$this->webDriver->getCurrentURL());

        $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("html/body/nav[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a"))->click();

        $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Care Pathways')]"))->click();

        $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("//input[@type='search']"))->sendKeys("QA Harness: Test1");

    $element = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath(".//*[@id='package-list']/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/i"));

        $this->webDriver->moveToElement(WebDriverElement:: $element->isDisplayed())->perform();

  //$this->webDriver->action(WebDriverActions:: )->moveToElement($element)->perform();

//$this->webDriver->getMouse()->mouseMove($element->getCoordinates());
//        $this->webDriver->getMouse()->click();

        //$this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[3]"))->click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far to use Actions? If you have some code you could show us that you're having problems with, it'd make it a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for you response. I am using facebook php webdriver and I want to use Actions class to mouse hover on an element, trying different ways to do so, but not working. please help me where I am going wrong!

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
  $action = new WebDriverActions($this->driver); 
  $action->moveToElement($element_you_want)->perform();
```

Comment: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number

Answer (score 1):

use(this for remote webdrivers):

```
$action = $this->driver->action();
$action->moveToElement($element_you_want)->perform();
```